# Kendo Dropdownlist throwing error on filtering multiple columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a dropdownlist that uses a template and I am trying to filter both columns but keep getting this error when I try to filter

> Uncaught TypeError: (c || "eq").toLowerCase is not a function

here is the code for the dropdownlist

```
function populateCustomerDropDown(ddlCustomer, selectedValue) {
    TryCatch(function () {
        $(ddlCustomer).empty();
        $(ddlCustomer).kendoDropDownList({
            optionLabel: "Select Customer...",
            dataTextField: "LastName",
            dataValueField: "CustomerID",
            filter: [
                {field: "LastName", operator: "contains"},
                { field: "FirstName", operator: "contains" }
            ],
            template: "<table style='width=500px; table-layout: fixed;'><colgroup><col style='width:200px;'><col style='width:300px;'></colgroup><tbody><tr><td style='border-style:solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:lightgrey; padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 2px;'>${ FirstName}</td><td style='width:200px; border-style:solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:lightgrey; padding-right: 2px; padding-left: 2px;'>${ LastName }</td></tr><tbody></table>",
            dataSource: {
                data: CustomersList
            }
        });

        if (selectedValue != null) {
            var dd = $(ddlCustomer).data("kendoDropDownList");
            dd.value(selectedValue);
            dd.trigger("change");
        }
    });
```

}

I have looked at the documentation and I believe that I have it set up properly, any idea's on why that error is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The dropdownlist [filter](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/filter) config does not seem to support setting composite filter. Only the operator for the text field. If you are trying to filter by both first and last name then you could add a field to the data that concatenates them and use it as text field or override the transport read function and manually filter the data:
https://dojo.telerik.com/@SiliconSoul/aZUzuJOd